# Alternative Large Cursors and show tooltips

Tags: macos, accessibility, cursor

I need to use large cursors when using OSX.

However the standard Apple ones I can choose in System Preferences all make the cursor expand to the right and down. These then hide the beginning of any tooltip (especially in web browsers) and in some programs they hide needed information.

I already use OmniDazzle to be able to find the cursor (and have used Pinpoint in the past) - it highlights the area the cursor is in but it does not change the cursor icon so it does not help me.

Are there any cursors or any way to expand the cursor in other directions so I can still read the tooltips?

Answer (score 4):

You can make custom cursors with a graphics program and apply them using [Pinpoint](http://www.lagentesoft.com/pinpoint/index.html). Here's the relevant [video](http://www.lagentesoft.com/tutorials/index.html#lightbox_stacks_in_264_page91) on how it's done.

Comment: It looks (from the video) like the default cursor has to stay visible. Perhaps the cursor set to its small size in addition to a custom icon would be a satisfactory solution.

Comment: I'm playing with the trial now and indeed the default cursor stays visible. However, the custom setting allow for vertical and horizontal offset of the custom icon relative to the default cursor.

Comment: Pinpoit FAQ says "PinPoint does not change the actual pointer in any way. This requires overriding Mac OS X and is not encouraged by Apple. Therefore, we do not do this. PinPoint adds to the existing pointer but does not replace it."

Comment: and their web pages are odd, can't select text and videos don't work for me.

Comment: Sorry it won't work for you. I agree it's a weird app but I think it's intended mainly for presentations. As you discovered, short of hacking the OS your options are limited.

Comment: The downvote however I feel is undeserved.

Comment: The downvote is because as far as I can see it does not chnage the cursor which is the question - the FAQ explicitly says it does not, If you know otherwise please show

Answer (score 2):

I think [Mouseposé](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mousepose/id405904955?mt=12) or [PinPoint](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pinpoint/id408265505?mt=12) will help you out by providing a  highlight around a normal size cursor that isn't opaque like the normal cursor so you can still read the tooltips.  They're not free, but it may be your only option.