# Trouble with Custom Mouse Pointer Colors and Transparency / Mouse Over text

Tags: mouse, color, accessibility, cursor

I use a giant cursor, and have it rendered as yellow outlined by red.  Yeah, my vision is bad enough that I really LOVE those features! (size and color of mouse pointer)

However, when I encounter mouse-over text, the cursor sits on top of it and I can't read most of it.  I've tried to quickly move the mouse pointer away, but that usually doesn't work.

I had the idea today to make my giant mouse pointer colors slightly transparent, so I could read the moused-over text through the pointer.

BUT if you set the transparency of the outline color below 92% it changes to white.

If you set the transparency of the fill color below 92% it turns black.

I understand that letting people turn down transparency all the way, you could lose the mouse pointer completely, so it makes sense that transparency is limited for the mouse colors.  But it seems like a 50% or 75% opaque would still allow the cursor to be seen AND still see the text that's behind it.

At 92% opaque, you can sort of see the text behind the cursor, it's not a complete failure, but it's very faint.

Does anybody know about this subject in more depth.  Because it's a real-world accessibility issue, I'd like to tell Apple about it?

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Bummer, no takers yet.  I could offer a bounty for a fix I guess.

Comment: I think the answer is no see also https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/91253/237

Comment: Still having this issue.  Link to other question shows link to "Pinpoint", but I guess they're no longer in business (bad links now).  Just adding a couple tags to help Apple maybe find this: Apple, accessibility, low vision, OSX, macOS, mouse-over, tool tips, mouse pointer, mouse cursor, custom colors.

Comment: As I pointed out in response to that answer it is no use as all it does is show where the cursor is. Note the answer is not accepted - and you can't tell but I voted it down.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a workaround:

You can set macOS such that, if you hold the Command key down while mousing over things, it will display the tooltip text a much larger font, so that it's no longer obscured by the mouse pointer.

Under Settings / Accessibility / Zoom / Hover Text, enable that switch.  Also I like to have the large text on a yellow background, which can be changed by clicking the "i" in a circle to the right of the toggle switch, this brings up a new window where you can change the "Background color"

Now, when mousing over things, hold down the Control key (the 4 leaf clover); if it doesn't immediately change the tooltip you're viewing, just move the pointer away and back while still holding the control key, and it will be enlarged.

Comment: I am confused control is no the four leaf clover - that is command control is <kbd>^</kbd.

Comment: I don't understand how hover works - e.g. on setting its details chhose it location and I get a popu window showing the height, How do you get only to work on command mouse not on every text field